# How to combine real-time and historical data for moving average calculation in DolphinDB?

Tags: streaming, lookup, dolphindb

There is a DolphinDB stream table containing the real-time closing price for a specific financial instrument. I want to combine the real-time data with the historical data stored in a DFS table to calculate moving averages for every 10-minute interval. Could you share an efficient method to achieve this data association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookup join engine. For more details, see [createLookupJoinEngine — DolphinDB 2.0 documentation](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/c/createLookupJoinEngine.html).